# UICollectionView: Adding item at a specified Index and scroll to this item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have created a vertical scrolling custom layout for my `UICollectionView`. Items are added to this collection through a classic pull to add and shown in alphabetical order. 
If I add an Item that starts with the Z letter it will be probably placed at the end of the collection so I want the collection to scroll automatically to show this last cell.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
 [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            // Update the datasource
            [self updateTasks]; 

            // Insert the new item into the collection
            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.tasks indexOfObject:task] inSection:0]]];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            // reload data and scroll 
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.tasks indexOfObject:task] inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        }];
```

It works... but as you can see I use `performBatchUpdates` to add my item. So the `UICollectionView` is automatically animated to present the new cell and shift the other cells. 
This animation is not shown if the `UICollectionView` has to scroll. Probably because the scrollview is animating too...

In your opinion which is the best way to insert an item in a collection view and to scroll to this new Item? I'm having hard time trying to obtain a beautiful and smooth animation to show to the user its new item in a fashion way.

**EDIT-------**

If I remove the call to `reloadData` the method `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` doesn't work... the uicollectionView doesn't scroll at all.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to reload data if you are using performBatchUpdate. Remove `[self.collectionView reloadData];` from completion block and it should works.

Comment: If I remove reload data the scrollToItemAtIndexPath function doesn't work.